# Microsoft Q#: "Namespace declarations can only occur at a global scope" error

Tags: programming, q#

[image]

I am having challenges with Microsoft Q#. I wrote this short code and it says it can only occur at a global scope.

How do I fix this error? Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: thanks is working

Answer (score 1):

This error is about the “global scope” of the namespace declaration, which is unrelated to the “global phase” mentioned in your Q# code.

In Q# Jupyter notebooks, code is automatically wrapped in a namespace - there is no need to declare one in your code. If you remove the `namespace Quantum.Kata.SingleQubitGates` declaration from your code, it should work.